# How to break lines automatically when there are inline code format?

Tags: line-breaking

My TeX have a lot of inline code to compile, so sometimes the output of PDF seems like this:

[image]

The outlined part is coded in `{\tt set_task_state(current_state)}`, How to automatically break the line within the `set_task_state(current_stat)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line breaking for monotype font is a hard issue. Below, five options (really less since some of them produce results which are not acceptable); I'd suggest you to use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package instead of just `\ttfamily` (by the way, `\tt` is deprecated and shouldn't ne used anymore) to write your listings. I loaded  `showframe` to have a visual guide of the text area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{showframe}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}

The method {\ttfamily set_current_state(current_state)} is synonimous to {\ttfamily set_task_state(current_state)}

The method \lstinline|set_current_state(current_state)| is synonimous to \lstinline|set_task_state(current_state)|

{\sloppy
The method \lstinline|set_current_state(current_state)| is synonimous to \lstinline|set_task_state(current_state)|\par}

{\sloppy
The method {\ttfamily set_current_state(current_state)} is synonimous to {\ttfamily set_task_state(current_state)}\par}  

{\raggedright
The method \lstinline|set_current_state(current_state)| is synonimous to \lstinline|set_task_state(current_state)|\par}

{\raggedright
The method {\ttfamily set_current_state(current_state)} is synonimous to {\ttfamily set_task_state(current_state)}\par}

{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\the\font=`\-}%
The method {\ttfamily set_current_state(current_state)} is synonimous to {\ttfamily set_task_state(current_state)}\par}

\end{document}
```

## The result

[image]

## Some comments

Using `linebreaks=true` enables line-break points; however, in this case, the verbatim text still protrudes.

Using `sloppy` leaves horrible big gaps between words.

Using `\raggedright` gives a somehow better and acceptable result here.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to combine two methods: to allow breakpoints at `_` characters and to allow larger spaces if needed. The first method is realized by setting `_` as active (using `\tth` instead `\tt`) and the second method needs to set the `\emergencystretch` register to the appropriate value:

```
{\catcode`\_=13 \gdef_{\string_\-}}
\def\tth{\tt\catcode`\_=13 }
\emergencystretch=3em

\hsize=14cm % for example

The method {\tth set_current_state(current_state)} is synonimous to
{\tth set_task_state(current_state)}.

\bye
```

You are probably using plain TeX (congratulations) because LaTeX users hate the `\tt`. So, my example is for plain TeX.